# json javascript not printing the correct output

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

I am new to javascript and I'm trying to convert a valid json string into a table. here is my code:

```
function printTable(){
    var txt = $("#txtInput").val();
    var obj;
    try {
        obj = JSON.parse(txt);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    var str = "<thead><th>name</th> <th>population</th> <th>capital</th> <th>currency</th> </thead>";
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
        var country = obj[i];
        str+="<tr><td>";
        str+=country.name+"</td>";
        str+="<td>"+country.population+"</td>";
        str+="<td>"+country.capital+"</td>";
        str+="<td>"+country.currency+"</td>";
    }
    $("#table").append(str);
}
```

the problem is, it is not printing the correct output. it prints "name population capital currency". the `JSON` string is:

> {
>     "countries": [
>         {"name": "France", "population": "66000000", "capital": "Paris", "currency": "eur"},
>         {"name": "Germany", "population": "82620000", "capital": "Berlin", "currency": "eur"},
>         {"name": "Norway", "population": "5233000", "capital": "Oslo", "currency": "nok"},
>         {"name": "Russia", "population": "144526000", "capital": "Moscow", "currency": "rub"}
>       ] 
>   }

I would appreciate any help. thank you.

Comment: Your code never appends a `</table>` to the string.

Comment: @Pointy why do you say that?

Comment: @Ele oh I guess `("#table")` may be an already-empty table element on the page; OK then. However I've had problems with IE in the past adding plain `<tr>` rows to a table without a wrapper `<tbody>`.

Comment: @Pointy good point about `tbody`

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over `obj.countries` and get every country as follow:

```
var country = obj.countries[i];
```

Another consideration, is adding the TRs within the `tbody` tag.

```js
function printTable(){
     var txt = '{ "countries": [ {"name": "France", "population": "66000000", "capital": "Paris", "currency": "eur"}, {"name": "Germany", "population": "82620000", "capital": "Berlin", "currency": "eur"}, {"name": "Norway", "population": "5233000", "capital": "Oslo", "currency": "nok"}, {"name": "Russia", "population": "144526000", "capital": "Moscow", "currency": "rub"} ]}';
     
    var obj;
    try {
        obj = JSON.parse(txt);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    var str = "<thead><th>name</th> <th>population</th> <th>capital</th> <th>currency</th> </thead><tbody>";
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.countries.length; i++){
    
        var country = obj.countries[i];
        str+="<tr><td>";
        str+=country.name+"</td>";
        str+="<td>"+country.population+"</td>";
        str+="<td>"+country.capital+"</td>";
        str+="<td>"+country.currency+"</td>";
    }
    $("#table").append(str + "</tbody>");
}


printTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something more like below so that there isn't so much string concatenation:

```
<table id="countryTable"></table>
```

Javascript

```
json = '{ "countries": [ {"name": "France", "population": "66000000", "capital": "Paris", "currency": "eur"}, {"name": "Germany", "population": "82620000", "capital": "Berlin", "currency": "eur"}, {"name": "Norway", "population": "5233000", "capital": "Oslo", "currency": "nok"}, {"name": "Russia", "population": "144526000", "capital": "Moscow", "currency": "rub"} ] }';

obj = JSON.parse(json);

obj.countries.forEach(displayCountry);

function displayCountry(country,index){
  var table = document.getElementById("countryTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var name = row.insertCell(0);
  var population = row.insertCell(1);
  var capital = row.insertCell(2);
  var currency = row.insertCell(3);

  name.innerHTML = country.name;
  population.innerHTML = country.population;
  capital.innerHTML = country.capital;
  currency.innerHTML = country.currency;

}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DanielGale/4sf0x6mn/)